# Cannot find lapack library in Photran Eclipse

Tags: windows, fortran, linker-errors, lapack, photran

I have some problems with building a Fortran program on Windows. I use Photran Eclipse with an autogenerated makefile but there are some problems with the lapack library.

Lapack packages were installed to Cygwin during the installation.

Error messages that are returned during the build process:

> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/11/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lC:/cygwin64/lib/lapack/cygblas-0.dll
>
> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/11/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lC:/cygwin64/lib/lapack/cyglapack-0.dll

What caused this problem?

[image]

Comment: How do you compile the code? What címmands do you execute? Where is your LAPACK installed? How is it configured in your Photran?

Comment: This `-lC:/...` looks like nonsense. You normally put there just the name of the library *without* the leading `lib`. The paths are controlled elsewhere.